# Plotting dataframe created using pandas with a CSV file. Having trouble with x axis tick labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want the x axis tick marks to be the different states ie. IDLE, Data=Addr, Hammer, etc that are in column A of the csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_csv("Output.csv", index_col = 0)
df1.plot(x = df1.index.values)
```

I have also tried

```
df1.plot(xticks = df1.index.values)
```

without any success.

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mxrx.png)

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVGP1.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [Seaborn](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn) because it looks like it is not a plotting issue but rather peripheral styling issue (all blacked out) in your environment.

Once you installed Seaborn, insert a piece of code below to yours.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
```

As a side note, if you wish to align the number of ticks in x axis to that of labels you have, replace your plotting part with the following:

```
df1.plot()
plt.xticks(range(df1.shape[0]), df1.index)
```

Hope this helps.